# What is the difference between $f$ in $L^p$ and $f\in \mathcal L^p$ ?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't really understand the difference between the equivalence classe and the function. So $\mathcal L^p$ is the set of function that are Lebesgue integrable and $L^p=\mathcal L^p/_\sim$ where $f\sim g\iff f(x)=g(x)$ a.e.

To be honnest, I never really distinguish $f$ and $g$ if $f=g$ a.e., but I know they are different (up to a null set). For example, in $L^p$ is doesn't really make sense to evaluate a function at a point $x$ since $\{x\}$ has measure $0$ and thus $f(x)$ can be anything... Even if $f=0$ a.e., at a fix point (say $0$), $f(0)$ can be anything. So what is the subtlety between $L^p$ and $\mathcal L^p$, because in a way, in $L^p$ for example $\boldsymbol 1_\mathbb Q$ and $0$ are the same, but in $\mathcal L^p$ they are totally different. I have the impression that element of $\mathcal L^p$ are function whereas element in $L^p$ are not really function... (we can't evaluate them). Could someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 2):

The elements of $L^p$ are sets, each of whose elements is a function in $\mathcal{L}^p$. For example, $0$ (the zero function) is not in $L^p$, but $[0] = \{f \in\mathcal{L}^p | f(x) = 0\mbox{ a.e}\}$ is in $L^p$. Conveniently, all other elements of $L^p$ are just shifts of this: $[f] = \{g + f | g \in [0]\}$. Often, we are lazy about notation and drop the brackets, saying something like "$f$ is in $L^p$", but always with the understanding that what we really mean by that is $[f]$ is in $L^p$.

As for your example: $1_\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ are clearly different functions. But $[0] = [1_{\mathbb{Q}}]$, so if we're being lazy about our notation as above, we might drop those brackets, and say something like "$0 = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ in $L^p$", but we really just mean "$[0] = [1_\mathbb{Q}]$" (or equivalently, $0\sim 1_\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Your answer is very interesting (and true in theory). But in the practice I never see an element of $L^p$ as a set. I think the problem is really equivalent to "how do you see $4\pi$ ? As an angle or as a distance ?"